# Accessing nested report powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

```
Datawindow ldwc_addpay
dw_1.getChild("dw_addpay",ldwc_addpay)
if ldwc_addpay.rowCount() <> 0 then

    for li_nestctr = 1 to ldwc_addpay.rowCount()

        ls_payamt = ldwc_addpay.getItemString(li_nestctr,"pay_amt")

        if not isnull(ls_payamt) and trim(ls_payamt) <> '' then ls_payamt = in_cryptoapi.of_Decrypt(ls_payment,"Key") 
        ldwc_addpay.setItem(li_nestctr, "pay_amt_dummy", double(ls_payamt)) 
        setnull(ls_payamt)

    next

end if
```

> 2nd row and up returns nothing (zero) but 1st row return exact value.
>   **every row has a salary deduction etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetChild()` won't do. Use [Dot Notation](https://pbbraindump.wordpress.com/2008/05/25/dot-notation-direct-access/) instead.

Comment: thanks for this bro, getchild only works on composite now i know.